# Game theory exercise and uniform probability

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, game-theory, operations-research

Could someone please explain how was b) solved ?

I really don't understand how was solved, I believe it has something to do with uniform probability applyed to the currect entry of the matrix.

> [image]

Solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's see, for example, how the $\frac35$ in the upper left corner was derived.  If $P_1$ hits issue $1$ and $P_2$ hits issue $3$, then whatever the actual percentage favoring $P_1$ had been, it will increase by 3%. So $P_1$ will win if the original percentage was more than 47%, which happens 
$$
\frac{50-47}{50-45} = \frac35
$$
of the time.

Comment: Could you explain this "So $_1$ will win if the original percentage was more than $47%$" ?

Comment: Yes, since his vote will, in that corner, be increased by 3%, if it started out as 47.1% it will then become 50.1% and he will win.

Comment: What $P_1$ and $P_3$ denote?

Comment: I don't understand at all

Comment: I meant $P_2$ (player 2) not $P_3$.